# SRGS to capture a wildcard text in Universal Windows App

Tags: uwp, speech-recognition

I planning to use continuous recognition in my UWP application to recognize the following sentence

```
add meeting with sara to my todo
```

Here "**meeting with sara**" can be replaced with any text but "add" ... "to my todo" should be fixed

I tried it like this

```
<rule id="todoAdd">
  add
  <ruleref special="GARBAGE"/>
  to my todo
</rule>
```

But i got the result as "add ... to my todo" where the garbage value is replaced by "..." but I need the garbage value as well. How do I build a SRGS for this case ?

Comment: AFAIK, SRGS does not support wildcard.